# Condense information from multiple spreadsheets to one using python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt

I have perhaps a thousand invoices in Excel, all of which have the Client/Name in B2 with the address split into B3 and B4 with B3 having the Number and street name, and the city, state, and zip in B4. What I am trying to do is open each of these excel files, (all are in the same directory) and extract the name and address to create a new spreadsheet with the information in it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import glob
from xlrd import open_workbook, XL_CELL_TEXT
from xlwt import Workbook
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

invoices = glob.glob("C:\emma\*.xls")
wbook = Workbook()
wsheet = wbook.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
R = 0

for x in invoices:
    rbook = open_workbook(x)
    rsheet = rbook.sheet_by_index(1)
    ncell = rsheet.cell(1,1)
    acell1 = rsheet.cell(1,2)
    acall2 = rsheet.cell(1,3)
    name = ncell.value
    address = acell1.value + " " + acell2.value

    wsheet.write(R,0,name)
    wsheet.write(R,1,address)

    R = R + 1

wbook.save('addresses.xls')
wbook.save(TemporaryFile())
```

As of right now it does not function. Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\emma\emma.py", line 14, in <module>
    ncell = rsheet.cell(1,1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 399, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not quite sure what is causing this error.

Comment: `rbook.sheet_by_index(1)` - sheets are zero-based: do you mean the second sheet here?

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams was correct, adjusting the `rbook.sheet_by_index(1)` to `rbook.sheet_by_index(0)` made it work, as well as fixing the typo at `acall2 = rseet.cell(1,3)`.